# I'm getting "Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker LAPTOP-ABCDEFG:9092" Why do I get Laptop host name instead of localhost or zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm new to Kafka
I was looking into a tutorial for basics
I was able to start my zookeeper through - zookeeper-server-start.bat zookeeper.properties
I was also able to start Kafka through - kafka-server-start.bat server.properties

But my Kafka server shows the below

> INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
> [2023-07-12 19:00:22,099] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=forwarding]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker LAPTOP-ABCDEF:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
> [2023-07-12 19:00:22,099] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=alterPartition]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker LAPTOP-ABCDEF:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)

Instead it should be zookeeper:9092 or localhost:9092

Changing server.properties file listeners like below

```
listeners = PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

But ideally even without changing the server.properties file I should get localhost:9092 right?

Also I feel I made some changes because of which I'm getting my LAPTOP host name instead of localhost?

Answer (score 0):

`listeners` sets the server socket binding port

`advertised.listeners` sets the returns network address where Kafka can be accessed, and will default to the machine hostname.

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

And, no `zookeeper:9092` is not correct.

Also, the latest Kafka documentation shows how to start it **without** Zookeeper (it is soon to be removed entirely in future versions)